# How to Open New window on every Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a link , on click of the some link, new window should open, 
User can minimize that window and click on other link other window should be open. so there will be multiple windows.

There is one jQuery plug-in which doing the same but its works only in Firefox. Not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: As an aside: please make sure this is really what you want to do. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118567/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-force-opening-a-new-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use javascript function window.open() . One of the reference for using is here: http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank" />`?

Comment: It Open in New Tab, I want in New Window.

Comment: You don't really control this. You could use javascript's `window.open()`, which allows you to request certain window 'features'. See http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml for details (first google hit). Note that those features are merely suggestions, and any user agent is free to ignore them (or ignore your javascript altogether, which is why I suggested a plain old <a> in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
<script>
var i=1;
    function openWin2(){
        window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "Win"+i++, 'location=0');
    }
<script>

.....

<a href="javascript:openWin2()">Click to open window </a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use the *rel* attribute for links. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="external" />
```

In jQuery:

```
$('a[rel=external]').attr('target', '_blank');
```